Media controls are not clickable
The media controls in the notifications are not working in Android 14 but are working on Android 13. Are there any changes that were made in Android 14?
            Intent intentPrevious = new Intent(context, NotificationActionService.class)
                    .setAction(ACTION_PREVIOUS);
            pendingIntentPrevious = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                    intentPrevious, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE); 

